# Excel formula sumif match ignore #n/a

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I'm trying use sumif match and ignore #n/a

```
=SUMIF(e:e,k2,f:f)
```

If e column cells matches k2, then sum its f cell values. But I need this to ignore #n/a.

Comment: it would only sum where it matches the value from K2, and ignore anything else anyway ?

Answer (score 1):

Following formula should help.

```
=SUMIFS(F:F,E:E,K2,F:F,"<>#N/A")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula with CSE,

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(E1:INDEX(E:E, MATCH(1E+99, F:F))=K2, F1:INDEX(F:F, MATCH(1E+99, F:F))), 0))
```

[image]